# Installing Heatsink (XIGMATEK Gaia SD1283) onto Motherboard (ASRock X79 Extreme9 LGA 2011 Intel X79)

Tags: motherboard, heatsink

I recently have purchased: XIGMATEK Gaia SD1283, in the instructions it states two different type's for the installation of the Intel LGA 2011. It lists Type 1 and Type 2.

Now I have the Intel Core i7-3930K (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819116492)

and I have the ASRock X79 Extreme9 LGA 2011 Intel X79 (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157285)

What Type do I use for the installation of this heatsink?

[image: Intel Type 1]

[image: Intel Type 2]

Comment: umm can you define type 1 and 2? If we don't know what type 1 and type 2 in your instructions are we can't tell you the right way to install it. I can tell you the Corsair H100 just screwed directly on my sabertooth x79 no brace or clamp on the back at all.

Comment: I'll upload some high-resolution pictures when I get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Radoo is on the right track the Manual he links to is for non LGA2011 Sockets.

I believe the way LGA2011 works for this model is a choice. I personally would choose type 1 as the mounting brackes for the Type 1 screw into the heat sink and then screw into the motherboard.

Type 2 looks as if no mounting brackets are used but instead the heatsink is held into place by part #5 which is a crossbar.

I purchased the same processor so I understand the mounting differences of the LGA2011 socket however I have not seen or used this heatsink. From the website and manual though it looks as if they have taken the two above approaches for mounting and have chosen to leave it up to the installer to choose the preferred method of installation.

[LGA2011 Manual](http://www.xigmatek.com/console/uploadfiles/Image/product/GaiaSd1283/universal%20LGA%202011%20usermanual%20%28front%29.pdf)

Comment: I added pictures of the heatsink, but I would generally agree with your reasoning, and I'll mark your answer as correct unless someone else can come up with something.

Comment: @MikeHagstrom I hope you enjoy the 3930k.

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw in Cooler's User Manual, the Type I and Type II drawings are showing two different types of mounting systems. So, it's a matter of what system do you have.

[Proper User Manual](http://www.xigmatek.com/console/uploadfiles/Image/product/GaiaSd1283/universal%20LGA%202011%20usermanual%20%28front%29.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It should really be as simple as to, which one of the brackets fit the pinholes on the motherboard. One of them most likely will not fit. I purchased the Cooler Master N520 (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835103057) and was able to easily solve that issue by just looking and matching them.